# Vetor de grande tamanho em C

Tags: c, array, int

Estou estudando os tipos de dados da linguagem C. E hoje eu resolvi criar um vetor de tamanho muito grande, no caso, 10^8. Então, fiz um pequeno código em que declaro esse grande vetor (Sendo que o valor 10^8 cabe no tipo Int), preencho suas posições e tento acessar um determinado elemento dele. Porém, o programa não está sendo executado corretamente, nada acontece, embora nenhum erro de compilação esteja sendo exibido. Poderiam me indicar qual a forma correta de se criar um vetor de tamanho tão grande? Desde já obrigado!

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int vet[100000000], i;

  for (i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    vet[i] = i;

  printf("%d", vet[200]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aqui https://ideone.com/8qyNex rodou corretamente. Mas vai depender de seu ambiente e da memória disponível.

Comment: Complementando: dê uma estudada em stack e heap para entender a alocação de memória e porque quando se utiliza alocação dinâmica pode fugir do stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Existe um limite para alocação de memória para um processo/programa, isso é válido para qualquer linguagem de programação e ambiente. Se você ultrapassa determinado limite, processos no computador começarão a travar por falta de memória disponível (isso inclui processos do próprio Sistema Operacional). Provavelmente você atingiu esse limite.

Você pode, em vez de alocar estaticamente a memória para um vetor de 100000000 elementos (4 bytes x 100000000 = ~400 MB), utilizar o mecanismo de alocação dinâmica de memória da linguagem C.

Como funciona: Você aloca a memória necessária para armazenar uma unidade de informação no vetor por vez. No seu caso, a unidade de informação é um int (4 bytes) (desprezando informações de endereçamento e ponteiros).

Você pode ver mais detalhes sobre este processo [neste link](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/aloca.html).

Mas reforçando, isso não vai resolver o seu problema de alocar um vetor deste tamanho ou maior. Para isso você vai precisar de mais memória disponível.